# How can I type on this div element?

Tags: javascript, html

The code I have is this one below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.zoom {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  transition: transform .2s;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.zoom:hover {
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); /* Safari 3-8 */
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>click/put your mouse in the square</h1>
  
<div class="zoom"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

What I'm trying to do here is to write something in the box, how can I possibly do that?
NOTE: I don't want people to write on it, i want to write on it

Comment: simply `<div class="zoom">hello world</div>` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply put it in between the tags:

```html
<div class="zoom">Type whatever you want here</div>
```

You can do this with most other tags too:

```html
<p>Some text</p>
<h1>Some more text</h1>
```

From your example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.zoom {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  transition: transform .2s;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.zoom:hover {
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); /* Safari 3-8 */
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>click/put your mouse in the square</h1>
  
<div class="zoom">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, are you trying to let the user type stuff in or display text?

Comment: no, i want to write something on it

Comment: I updated the answer. If it answers your question, please select it as correct.

Comment: one more thing, in between which tags?

Comment: Opening and closing tags. An opening tag: `<h1>` or `<div>` or `<p>`. Closing tag: `</h1>` or `</div>` or `</p>`.

Comment: i know, but where do i place it? in the code?

Comment: The example you provided is correct. In between the opening and closing `<body>` tags.

Comment: ok, thanks, i would upvote you, but, i dont have enough rep -_-